# Loaded event for WebBrowser control in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, events, load, webbrowser-control

I need to access the below property of `WebBrowser` control when it is loaded completely.

```
webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
```

this is null if the control is not loaded completely.

What property/event  can I check like `Form_Load`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is WebBrowser.LoadComplete event for top-level only (the WebBrowser here I guess). If you're looking for an non top-level element, DocumentCompleted event occurs for all elements.

As ActiveXInstance is inherited from WebBrowserBase, there is also the Control.HandleCreated event, being fired when the control is displayed for the first time, though I don't know if it is applicable here.

(Sadly I'm not able to give the class and event links, but should be possible to find them yourself, right?)